# storing the data from listview to array & generate random value

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am very grateful for the answers provided by this site as it helped me a lot with my learning. The problem right now is, i cant seem to get my third column of data in listview into an array form.

I have a database which looks like this, WorkerID represent the Worker, TaskNo represent the task and Timetaken will represent how long is required for that particular worker to finish up that particular task.

```
+----------+--------+-----------+
| WorkerID | TaskNo | TimeTaken |
+----------+--------+-----------+
| 1        | 1      | 7.5       |
+----------+--------+-----------+
| 4        | 1      | 2.5       |
+----------+--------+-----------+
| 1        | 2      | 3.5       |
+----------+--------+-----------+
| 2        | 2      | 1.5       |
+----------+--------+-----------+
| 1        | 3      | 2.5       |
+----------+--------+-----------+
| 2        | 3      | 4.5       |
+----------+--------+-----------+
| 3        | 3      | 3.5       |
+----------+--------+-----------+
| 2        | 4      | 3.5       |
+----------+--------+-----------+
```

-and the list goes on-

With much help, i'm finally able to display it on vb like

```
+--------+------------+------------------+
| TaskNo | NumWorkers | WorkersAvailable |
+--------+------------+------------------+
| 1      | 2          | 1, 4             |
+--------+------------+------------------+
| 2      | 2          | 1, 2             |
+--------+------------+------------------+
| 3      | 3          | 1, 2, 3          |
+--------+------------+------------------+
| 4      | 1          | 2                |
+--------+------------+------------------+
```

This is an overview of my employee information, like for example how many workers are available for which task. Only two employee having the skill to carry out task number 1, both are Employee 1 & Employee 4.

Right now i am trying to put all value from "WorkersAvailable" only and store into an array.

- +----+-----+-------+--+
- |  1,4 | 1,2 | 1,2,3  | 2 |
- +---+------+-------+--+

By clicking on a button, i can generate out a string of random numbers, getting a available random number from workeravailable column.

example: **1**(row1),**1**(row2),**3**(row3),**2**(row4)... and so on

**Note:Only one worker is required for each task**

Each numbers represent a number from each row, separating by a comma.

- From Row 1, I can only random either number 1 or 4
- From Row 2, I can only random either 1 or 2
- From Row 3, I can only random either 1 or 2 or 3
- and so on

After generating a string of number(1,1,3,2).
I have to calculate the total time taken for one cycle of task to be completed. Each cycle represent completion of all the required task, one after another. Right now i have to check the database for the different timing, adding them up together to get the total time for one cycle.

### My Code

```
   Sub RefreshLv()

        Using conn = New OleDbConnection
            conn.ConnectionString = myConString
            conn.Open()

            Dim dt As New System.Data.DataTable("ListInfo")
            Using da

                ' fill the DataTable with three columns, the third column being a placeholder that we will fill in below
                Dim Sql As String = ("SELECT [TaskNo], COUNT(*) AS NumWorkers, '' AS WorkersAvailable " & "FROM ScheduleInfo GROUP BY [TaskNo]")
                da.SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand(Sql, conn)
                da.Fill(dt)

                Using cmd2 = New OleDbCommand()

                    ' create a Prepared Statement that we will use for each iteration
                    cmd2.Connection = conn
                    cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT [WorkerID] FROM ScheduleInfo " & "WHERE [TaskNo] = ? " & "ORDER BY [WorkerID]"
                    cmd2.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Integer)
                    cmd2.Prepare()

                    LstViewScheduleInfo.Columns.Add("TaskNo", 150, HorizontalAlignment.Center)
                    LstViewScheduleInfo.Columns.Add("No of Workers", 150, HorizontalAlignment.Center)
                    LstViewScheduleInfo.Columns.Add("Workers Available", 150, HorizontalAlignment.Center)

                    ' foreach row of the DataTable, build the string of WorkerID values
                    Dim RandomEmployee As New List(Of Integer)
                    Dim rnd As New Random

                    For Each dr As System.Data.DataRow In dt.Rows

                        Dim ListEmployee As New List(Of Integer)
                        Dim workerList As String = ""
                        cmd2.Parameters(0).Value = dr("TaskNo")
                        Using rdr As OleDbDataReader = cmd2.ExecuteReader()

                            While rdr.Read()
                                ListEmployee.Add(rdr("WorkerID"))
                                workerList += ", " & rdr("WorkerID")
                            End While
                        End Using

                        ' remove leading ", "
                        'Dim Qpass As String
                        dr("WorkersAvailable") = workerList.Substring(2)
                        Dim randomvalue As Integer = ListEmployee(rnd.Next(0, 2))
                        'Qpass = randomvalue.ToString()
                        'MessageBox.Show(Qpass)
                        RandomEmployee.Add(randomvalue)
                    Next
                    Dim zxc = String.Join((","), RandomEmployee.ToArray())
                    LblRandom1.Text = zxc

                End Using

                ' for demo purposes, just dump the DataTable to the console
                For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows()
                    Dim lst As ListViewItem
                    lst = LstViewScheduleInfo.Items.Add(dr(0))

                    For i As Integer = 1 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
                        lst.SubItems.Add(dr(i))
                    Next
                Next

            End Using
            conn.Close()
        End Using


    End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        RefreshLv()

 End Sub
    Private Sub BtnRandom_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnRandom.Click

        LstViewScheduleInfo.Clear()
        RefreshLv()

    End Sub
End Class
```

What i attempted is trying to get a List(of Integer) everytime my program loop through to check for the Workeravailable. Then pick a random number and use a messagebox to show which number it random. I know this is not right but i really have no idea where to call for random value in my program.
This is my first time touching on array, so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I am not clear on what you are asking. Please change wording. Also SO community likes code - add some to your question. And/Or screenshots of what you have VS what you want.

Comment: one way is to not jumble UI elements with the data model.  When you get WorkersAvail from the datasource save it in your code as data.  Rather than parsing a LV cell BACK into data elements, create a class to store the Workers avail for each task in a List(Of myClass), THEN format the worker list as "1, 2, 4" for *display*.

Comment: If your questions is "Is there any possible ways i could do it?" then the answer is naturally yes. You really need to rework this question into a very clear problem, your attempted solution and what answer you require.

Comment: One thing I note in your code is the line `Dim rnd As New Random`. It's within a loop so it is being reinstantiated many times. It is very likely that it will be seeded with the same value and then produce the same "random" values. You need to instantiate the `Random` class only once outside the loop.

Comment: @Enigmativity is it possible if i private the **Dim rnd As New Random** instead. is there any possible ways i could check what item has been added into my array? **ListEmployee.Add(rdr("WorkerID").ToString())** only show count = 15

Comment: @Crayon - Move the `rnd` declaration outside of the loop, that's all you need to do. Swap the line with the `For Each`. And, as for looking in your array, just use a breakpoint. That's a simple debugging exercise.

Comment: @Enigmativity for the **Dim randomValue As Integer = ListEmployee(rnd.Next())** part. what should i put inside the bracket?

Comment: @Crayon - That's really up to you. It's your code.